# syntax error near unexpected token `do'

Tags: bash

need help for creating this.

my requirement is need to take input from user and create the users in remote machine.

```
echo -n "Enter username: "
read UserName
echo -n "Enter Comment "
read Gecos
echo -n "Enter group: "
read Group
echo -n "Enter shell: "
read Shell
do
ssh -qt ftdcsldapp660.ftiz.cummins.com sudo /usr/sbin/useradd -u $Uid -g $Group -c "$Gecos" -d /usr/users/$UserName -m  -s $Shell $UserName
done


[opsunix@ftdcsldapp660 tmp]$ ./test.sh
Enter username: test
Enter Comment test
Enter group: teset
Enter shell: /bin/ksh
./test.sh: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `do'
./test.sh: line 9: `do'
[opsunix@ftdcsldapp660 tmp]$
```

but i am getting this error

Comment: Do you think it is wise to include the actual DNS name in your question? How would Cummins feel about that? Also, properly format your code; this is unreadable.

Comment: `do` is part of the syntax of `for` and `while`. But there's no `for` or `while` before it. Why isn't this obvious to you?

Comment: What purpose does the `do... done` serve? Where is the loop? What sort of loop is it meant to be?

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: first, I'll go with printf instead of echo

Answer (score -1):

Looks like a cut n paste error - there is a leftover "do" and "done" possibly from a former "while"

Here's a fixed version of the script

```
echo -n "Enter username: "
read UserName
echo -n "Enter Comment "
read Gecos
echo -n "Enter group: "
read Group
echo -n "Enter shell: "
read Shell
#do
ssh -qt ftdcsldapp660.ftiz.cummins.com sudo /usr/sbin/useradd -u $Uid -g $Group -c "$Gecos" -d /usr/users/$UserName -m -s $Shell $UserName
#done
```

Comment: Presumably, a loop should be supplying the value of `$Uid`. Whether that should be a `for` loop or a `while` loop (or even, improbably, an `until` loop) is unknown.

Comment: I agree Uid is missing but it seems to me this ssh is one-off and not meant to be in a loop - obviously the excerpt is from more general code that had a loop but a loop around just the ssh after info for a single user is entered interactively does not make sense